# I do not want divs to come side by side

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I do not want divs to come side by side. how can i solve this

search about -- > false

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="row ">
  <div class="col-md-8 "></div>
  <div class="col-md-4 d-flex justify-content-start">
    <div class="search">
      <p>search</p>
    </div>
    <div class="about">
      <p>about</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Show us your CSS for `.about` and `.search`.

Comment: i not have a css code yet

Comment: They do come underneath each other, as expected. See your own snippet.

Comment: ok i edited.  thank you.

Answer (score 0):

```css
.search {border: 1px solid #000; display: block!important;}
.about {border: 1px solid #000; display: block!important;}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="container">
<div class="row ">

<div class="col-md-8 ">
</div>

<div class="col-md-4">

      <div class="search">
        <p>search</p>
      </div>

      <div class="about">
        <p>about</p>
      </div>
</div>

</div>
```

on your CSS `div { display: block; }` , or you can give property to your classes, like:

```
.search { display: block;}
.about { display: block;}
```

if you want just to test if it works you can write it directly on the html, but change it to the CSS file as soon as you see that it works:

```
<div style="display: block;" class="search">
    <p>search</p>
  </div>

  <div style="display: block;" class="about">
    <p>about</p>
  </div>
```

Comment: How do the CSS look like?

Comment: if i add this code it does not work -  col-md-4 d-flex justify-content-start

Comment: try the snippet above, maybe if you add "!important" will work

Comment: are you trying using bootstrap 4 ?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried a `<br/>` tag between the divs?

Comment: i dont want use to br tag

Answer (score 0):

Remove class="col-md-4" from div

Comment: why ? i am using bootstrap

Answer (score 0):

```css
.search {border: 1px solid #000; display: block!important;}
.about {border: 1px solid #000; display: block!important;}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="container">
<div class="row ">

<div class="col-md-8 ">
</div>

<div class="col-md-4  d-flex justify-content-start">

      <div class="search">
        <p>search</p>
      </div>

      <div class="about">
        <p>about</p>
      </div>
</div>

</div>
```

Comment: Why would you add `!important` here? `.search` and `.important` are plain `div`s which are block elements by default. No need to add those rules at all.

Comment: what should we do ?

Comment: Remove `d-flex justify-content-start`. Notice the code you showed here is different from the one in your question.

Answer (score 0):

You can try adding this css style to the div elements:

```
div{
    clear:both;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It works perfectly in my browser. `<div>` tag is a block element by default. I think you should update your browser instead.

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="container">
<div class="row ">

<div class="col-md-8 ">
</div>

<div class="col-md-4">

      <div class="search">
        <p>search</p>
      </div>

      <div class="about">
        <p>about</p>
      </div>
</div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="container">
<div class="row ">

<div class="col-md-8 ">
</div>

<div class="col-md-4 d-flex justify-content-start">

      <div class="search">
        <p>search</p>
      </div>

      <div class="about">
        <p>about</p>
      </div>
</div>

</div>
```

d-flex justify-content-start -- if i add this code it does not work

Comment: Man, then DO NOT ADD THAT AS THAT IS THE CAUSE OF YOUR PROBLEM!